# How to get nokogiri attribute value?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

My xml contains multiple statements like

```
<House name="bla"><Room id="bla" name="black" ><blah id="blue" name="brown"></blah></Room></House>
```

I need to get all the values for the given keyword.

I used `nodes = doc.css("[name]")` to get the `<Room id="bla" name="black" ><blah id="blue" name="brown"></blah></Room>`.\

But how do I get the value for a key from this. Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: _"What I need to get is the value black"_ – based on what? Could you describe your requirements without using the word "black"?

Comment: @Stefan: modified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
node_names = doc.css("[name]").map { |node| node['name'] }
```

for all node names; or for just "black",

```
black = doc.at_css("[name]")['name']
```

Comment: second line is giving only the first occurance. Could you please add that statement as well if true.

Comment: Yup, the question was unclear regarding which one of those you wanted.

Comment: What if I need to get the data only if one more attribute in the same level contains some particular value. <test name="blah" param="blue">. I need name value only if param is blue.

Comment: `doc.at_css('[param="blue"]')['name']`

Comment: Is everything this simple in ruby :)

Comment: Ruby is happiness. But in this case, CSS selectors also help.

Comment: One more question currently I asked related to the above question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40103791/how-to-get-nokogiri-parent-attribute-value