# How to get XML parent attribute value

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have multiple statements like:

```
<House name="test1">
     <Room id="test2" name="test3" >
           <test name="test4" param="test5">
                 <blah id="test6" name="test7">
                 </blah>
           </test>
     </Room>
</House>
```

When the `blah name` is some particular value like `test7` I need the corresponding Room name. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used Nokogiri but I tried and this seems to work:

```
 xml_doc.css('blah[name="test7"]').first.ancestors("Room").first['name']
 => "test3"
```

Just check for `nil`s.

```
2.3.1 :132 > xml_doc.css('blah[name="test7"]').map { |node| node.ancestors("Room").first['name'] }
 => ["test3"]
```

Comment: How did you do this in first attemp if You have not used nokogiri? I will try this code.

Comment: I read the docs and made some google searches. And tried in irb.

Comment: I want all the output not the first['name']) how do I do it. Removing first['name'] doesn't work.

Comment: "I need the corresponding Room name". What do you need? The entire XML  fragment of the Room element?

Comment: No, What you wrote is fine, but I think my question was not clear. If those above xml statements are repeated multiple times, I want all Room names.

Comment: This is exactly what I want :)

Comment: Excellent bro! ^_^

Comment: why do we need to use .first['name'], can't we just use ['name'] ?

Comment: Because ancestors returns a NodeSet

Comment: Instead of `css(...).first` use either `at(...)` or `at_css(...)`.